# Send Mouse Clicks to a Minimized C# Application using The Same App

Tags: c#, click, sendmessage

There're a lot of ways to simulate a mouse click in an inactive window. I want my program to make clicks even when it's minimized and of course without capturing the main mouse.

Specifically, my C# program will contain a Web Control displaying some flash content and this is where I want the clicks to occur.

here's the techniques I tried:

1.`[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);`

2.`[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SendMessage(int hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);`

Both of them did not do any good in my case. Surprisingly, I was able to use the `SendMessage()` function to send mouse clicks in a minimized chrome displaying some flash content. but, it doesn't seem to do that in my C# program. Is there a possibility that my program not receiving the message for some reason?

Any Hints on how can I do this?

Comment: Inject javascript into the web control. Google "C-sharp javascript injection"

Comment: I read a bit about the JS injections, as I understood they're shortcuts to reduce time and effort via the JS entered in the URL, what's the codes I might use in JS, or how to put this in my favor in this problem?

Comment: No - javascript injections don't have anything to do with the url. They execute javascript on the web page the same way as if entered by the programmer. You can, for example, execute a button click by injecting a Document.GetElementById("MyButton").Click() In this manner, you can interact with any part of the DOM, and manipulate anything on the web page.

Comment: Now - if you're attempting to modify the Flash itself (as in breaking a game), then you will need to modify the bytecode unless the flash has exposed actionscript via javascript. You haven't really stated what your purpose is.

Comment: Thanks Shannon Holsinger, my purpose is to be able to execute clicks while having the program minimized much like automating something in it, I'll more into this.

Comment: Is it your flash? If so, you can expose methods to the DOM. If not, then you'll likely have to break the bytecode or use Fiddler.

Comment: yes the clicks will occur on the flash content, so GetElementById won't work?

Comment: If you own the flash and expose methods, then something like that will work. If you don't own the flash and only have the .swf file, then you'll have to use Fiddler or otherwise break the bytecode. Google flash bytecode or flash fiddler for more information

Comment: the flash content will be a game so I won't have even the .swf file

Comment: Yeah okay then I misunderstood your original question. There should be some ample resources out there under Google for "hack flash game" or "break flash bytecode" - that's crossing the line into black hat for this site -- can't help you more than that.

Comment: This is not a hack, much like a process automation in the background, and Thank you for you efforts